# HP mini reboots after a few days and cannot finds its boot drive. Any idea why?

Tags: windows-7, boot, reboot

I have a HP mini netbook running Windows 7 Ultimate.

I usually leave it running with the lid shut and connected to power. This worked well for two years.

For the past few weeks, I usually find the mini displaying the text "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key".

Apparently the mini decides to reboot and forget its boot drive.

Switching it off and on eventually results in the mini booting again.

Any idea why this happens? There seems to be nothing special in event viewer.

Comment: How many times (average) is eventually?  It sounds  as if the drive motor doent kick the platters into spin easily?  It is a hard drive right?  That could be 2 things, weak power source, or worn hard drive.  If you listen to it closely (assuming you can hear over the fan), how goes the spin up?  and how goes the first head read? then when it does work how is it different?  Be it Flash or Mechanical drive, if you have an Easy way of re-writing all the data without loosing any of it, it would be the first thing I would try, just a solid re-write of everything.

Comment: The hard drive works fine. The computer works when I use it. I can switch it on, boot it, use it, play with it and so on. It's only after a while that it suddenly reboots and cannot finds its boot device any more.

Comment: ok, scratch that, because that sounds more like a power and/or heat issue instead. when you treat it cooler, without causing cold issues (like condensation) does that change anything?

Comment: It's really not particularly hot where the computer is located. The mystery is really why it forgets its boot device after the sudden reboot. Heat issues could explain the sudden reboot but not why it forgets its boot device until the next cold start.

Comment: what if it did the reboot, because the device was lost first causing the initial reboot/problem. (I think that was possible in XP)  Did you turn off Auto Restart on crash, did you check the event logs? (to get the error, not to believe it means what it says :-)

Comment: Good idea. That will tell me whether the problem is a crash or a reboot. I checked the event logs but couldn't find anything except a system that clearly didn't know what was coming.

Comment: I turned off the auto restart and so far the netbook has remained online.

Comment: I found it powered off two hours later.

Comment: "The previous system shutdown at 18:25:50 on 21/12/2011 was unexpected."

Comment: There is nothing in the event log for that time and only good news messages from an hour before that and earlier.

Comment: that leaves (something like) checking if this is a sleep or standby problem, or possible hardware problem. does it happen if it is activly kept awake endlessly? (power options) New program that causes fits because hard drive slept?

Comment: The system is configured not to fall asleep unless not connected to a power source. There are no new programs on it. I did find that Microsoft Security Essentials caused a few odd errors and uninstalled it. Maybe that will fix it magically.

Comment: I'll check if it is a hardware problem. I'll install Linux and see if it happens again.